Does the Riddle Story of The Devil Special Make Sense?
Is the Riddle Story of Devil Special a remix of the prequel or does it make sense? I ask this because I feel like they were on another mission against Haru to get whatever they wanted. They had to get Haru's pink pin before sundown to win, just like they had to kill Haru in 48 hours. So, does this special make sense or should it have been different?
